Http library plug in and Thonny
When I try to install the plug in in Thonny, is gives the following error:
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Ã— python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  â”‚ exit code: 1
  â•°â”€> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\murra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cuurl_zh\http_ee079edca8e844c58bb74db1119342d8\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
          import http
        File "C:\Users\murra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cuurl_zh\http_ee079edca8e844c58bb74db1119342d8\http\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
          from request import Request
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Ã— Encountered error while generating package metadata.
â•°â”€> See above for output.

I tried installing it from GitHub directly and adding the add on from the zip file, but that did not work either.

ok, I'll try that,
thanks

Murray, Sorry, I couldn't get http to install in pycharm either!  I'll let you know if I get it to work.

ok thank you ------

While I certainly don't want to discourage you from using https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ I don't think that it's Thonny that is at fault.  Further, you will find pycharm more work to use, although I think it's worth it.  The more modern way, however, is to use the python requests package instead of http.

thank you for your help! - hopefully this works.

Here is a simple example of using requests which runs in Thonny:
import requests

# URL for the HTTP request
url = 'https://google.com'

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request was successful!")
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve data. Status code: {response.status_code}")

